# How to choose the best framework for mobile app design?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, parse-platform

I'm getting more and more confused about choosing a right framework to kick start the mobile app development for any mobile os platform. I find something like phonegap, parse, KindoUI, JQuery Mobile etc. Please suggest someone what to choose on which basis?  Are they all does the same work? Whether it is right to learn each platform individually or go with frameworks which will cover all the platforms?

Comment: Refer this you will get to know difference between all frameworks. so that you can use whatever you you feel good to use. http://html5hub.com/comparing-html5-mobile-ui-frameworks/

Comment: Thankz @Suhas. These are all html5 frameworks. I want to know all the frameworks not just only html 5 frameworks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a good fit for cross platform mobile development using the following technologies:

[AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/developer/) (I started with Phonegap build and moved to the CLI when I was a bit more experienced. ) , [Parse](https://parse.com/) .

This 3 techs cover different needs,

**AngularJS** as an "open-source JavaScript framework, maintained by Google, that assists with running single-page applications. Its goal is to augment browser-based applications with model–view–controller capability".

**Phonegap** "Enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3, instead of device-specific languages such as Objective-C"

**Parse.com** : Provides a suite of cloud services for developers that are tightly coupled with SDKs for all the major client platforms. Recently bought by FB. Parse is/was one of the external BaaS providers amongst many others like StackMob, Apigee and dozens of cloud and VPS providers like EC2, Heroku, etc..

However this is my choice given my previous experience, the technollogies I wanted to discover and what I found when I was researching. There is probabily no such a think as the best framework though . . .

Comment: Thankz @Arcayne.. Probably u re right.There is no such best framework It depends on your need and expertise level.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at a german backend as a service provider [apiOmat](http://apiomat.com); they offer a lot of features and pretty cool generated SDKs. And, in contrast to many others, data is not hosted by NSA but in germany.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at the [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/)  framework. I worked on an app which was created using Jquery Mobile with PhoneGap. I must say it was quite a bit sluggish when it comes to performance.

Then, I opted for **Sencha Touch** which eventually resulted in a better performance. The good thing about Sencha is that the framework provides everything that you need in one place. You can try Sencha Architect (IDE from Sencha) which holds all the controls for you to develop an application (please note that Sencha Architect is commercial but you can give yourself a try on Evaluation pack). You need to spend a bit of time to learn and see this works. Performance is also good when it is compared to Jquery Mobile. So, my suggestion would be to you try **Sencha Touch** along with **PhoneGap/Cordova**.

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wrapping up a mobile app project with jquery mobile/phonegap/apigee and it worked great for me.

I would say build a hello world project for each that you're considering, and see what you like, most comfortable with. If you're already familiar with jquery, jquery mobile is a fairly easy transition. That and phonegap keep getting better and better, so those are good signs.

Comment: Thankz @Joe i have already done hello world on Phonegap and JQuery Mobile. But your answer is not complete to my question.